# Adding ChildViewController to UIAlertController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, viewcontroller

I want to have a custom view in my alert dialog along with OK and Cancel button.
I want to inject a viewController in runtime in the alertViewController.  Though it inherits from ViewController but the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014538-CH1-SW2) clearly states

> The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

Is there an alternative way to get this done.

Answer (score 0):

As the message says, you can't subclass `UIAlertController`.  Just use it as-is and use `UIAlertAction` to add the actions you want to take ('Ok', 'Cancel', etc).

If that doesn't work for what you want, you'll have to create a new ViewController (xib and class) and design it to look & do what you want.

Comment: This is what I wanted to avoid writing another view controller . alert dialog does lot of work without coding much